# Contacts field in Outlook task

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

We updated the CEOs Office last week from 2010 Standard to 2016 Standard and all went well in the beginning.

Then it turned out he was having tons of tasks in which he uses the **Contacts** field. This field was displayed in the task view in Office 2010 right at the bottom of the window and is missing in Office 2016, it's neither in the normal **Task** view nor in the **Details** pane.

Then he said no problem, if I could migrate the content of the contacts field over to the **Company** field which yes is displayed under the Details pane he would be fine.

I did this and thought he would be fine, but then he said he cannot sort the items as he was used to, he used to group the tasks by **Categories** and sort them by **Contacts** but no matter what I do, under the View settings the field **Company** which the contacts were migrated to, won't show up under the Sorting options.

Then I started to create a custom task form, add a custom pane with the Contacts field and I was able to configure it as the default form for the folder and new tasks are getting created with that form but **existing** tasks still use the default form where he cannot see the Contacts field.

After hours of googling I still have three questions left:

- Is there a way to configure the new custom form as default form for **all** existing task and tasks being created?
- Is there another way to make the Contacts field show up in the default tasks form?
- Is there a way to make the Company field show up under the sorting options of the Tasks' view settings?

Comment: Maybe you can make your problem more clearer with some screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing around another few hours, I finally found an [article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/outlook-2013-show-contacts-below-the-notes-field/43f973a7-157c-4fd1-a405-d10c218d9e7e) that described how to bring the contacts field back to the tasks main view.

I had to just create a new `DWORD` under the following key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook\Preferences`, name it `showcontactfieldobsolete` and give it a value of 1.

This brought back that field and solved the problem for me.

Thanks